# Error Singleton in c++

Tags: c++

What is the problem?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Singleton
{
    public:
        void HelloWorld();

        static Singleton* Instance(){
        if (instanza == 0)
            instanza = new Singleton ;
        return instanza;
        }

    protected:
        Singleton();

    private:
        static Singleton* instanza;
};


Singleton* Singleton:: instanza = 0;

void Singleton::HelloWorld()
{
    cout << "Hello World!";
}
int main()
{
    Singleton *p = Singleton ::Instance();
    p->HelloWorld();
    delete p;
}
```

g++ -Wall -o "singleton" "singleton.cpp" (nella cartella: /home/tarek/Scrivania/Nuovi codici)
/tmp/ccL8BxOT.o: nella funzione "Singleton::Instance()":
singleton.cpp:(.text._ZN9Singleton8InstanceEv[_ZN9Singleton8InstanceEv]+0x24): riferimento non definito a "Singleton::Singleton()"
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Compilazione fallita.

Comment: Show us english errors. Just state `LANG=C` in front of the g++ command.

Comment: The message is pretty clear: `Singleton::Singleton()` is not defined.

Comment: *What is the problem?* is what you should report. Stackoverflow isn't remote debugging service. And your singleton idiom is broken - what if `Instance` is called before `instanza = 0`? Use local static variables for singletons.

Comment: You forgot to write constructor definition.

Comment: Off topic suggestion: Consider replacing what you have with a Meyers Singleton. It could be as simple as `static YourType& instance()
{
     static YourType s;
     return s;
}`. More complete discussion in the top answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008019/c-singleton-design-pattern?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 4):

Your constructor is just declared not defined.

change it to

```
...
 protected:
        Singleton() {};//add further implementation here
        //Singleton() = default; for c++11
...
```

and it should work

Answer (score 0):

You would need define constructor as

```
Singleton::Singleton() 
{
}
```